# Click to scroll through testimonials

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

List is setup to cycle through testimonials.
I would like to add left and right arrows to this so users can scroll also.

JS [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w1o5ksyn/) below with current setup

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var divs = $('li[class^="testimonial-"]').hide(),
    i = 0;

  (function cycle() {
    divs.eq(i).fadeIn(800)
      .delay(5000)
      .fadeOut(800, cycle);

    i = ++i % divs.length;
  })();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="testimonials" style="list-style-type: none; padding-left:0;">
  <li class="testimonial-1">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
  </li>

  <li class="testimonial-2">
    It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Don't use delay. Maybe use `setTimeout` and `clearTimeout`.

Comment: what do you expect exactly?